# How I Can Change The Divi Mobile Menu Icon?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

How can I change the Divi mobile menu icon?

I want my mobile menu icon to be changed in the Divi theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy and paste the following little snippet into the Divi>Theme Options>Custom CSS box.

`/*change Divi hamburger menu to X*/ .mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before { content: '\4d'; }`